# Show collection of data using while loop

Tags: laravel-5.8

How can I show collection of data using while loop in blade file? Suppose I have some data like this

```
$products = Product::latest()->where('status', 1)->get();
return view('products', compact('products'));
```

Now in this case how can I write this $products variable in my products.blade.php file.? I don't wana use @foreach loop. Can anybody help me.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel Collection's get method to retrieve a 'row' at a given key.

```
@php $i=0; @endphp
@while($i < $products->count())
    {{ $products->get($i)->name }}
    @php $i++; @endphp
@endwhile
```

Comment: Thanks man it works, but don't works with `@php $i=0; @endphp` it's work with `@php($i = 0)`

Comment: Oh! Welcome @ShekhSaifuddin. Thanks for the feedback too. Did ```@php $i++; @endphp``` work as it is? Wondering why ```@php($i = 0)``` was needed to make code work?

Comment: no Brother we should edit two places, like this `@php($i = 0)` and `@php($i++)`, but I'm also wonder why this `@php $i=0; @endphp` not work..!!! Btw many many Thanks man.

Comment: Because, as you show the thing as simple way, I have no found anywhere in this way..

Comment: You're Welcome... :) Will check and study @php thing, and will let you know. Thanks... :)